# Selenium tests timeout in Saucelabs but are shown as passed in Jenkins. How to show the job as failed when tests timeout in Saucelabs ?

Tags: selenium, junit, jenkins, saucelabs

I run Selenium tests on Saucelabs by creating a job in Jenkins. Some of the tests timeout on Saucelabs due to network issue or auth challenge. The result of the job in Jenkins is shown  as successfully passed. How do I get the error to be shown on Jenkins job ? Is there a way to make the job fail when tests timeout ? Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1):

If there is a string that you can search for in the console log output that indicates when the tests have timed out, you can use the [Text Finder plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Text-finder+Plugin) to look for that string and fail the build.

Comment: Jenkins console output does not have any string which could be used to determine if tests were timed out.If 6 tests were running and 4th gets timed out Saucelabs shows timeout error but Jenkins shows job successful with 3 tests as passed 0 failed 0 skipped.

Answer (score 0):

If your test loses connection to the grid while its running, then Sauce will timeout (after 90 seconds of inactivity in JSON packeets) and because there is no connection from your tests, there is no way for your tests to know that it happened.    Unless you set a timeout on your Junit or TestNG test so that if the long timeout is reached you are certain it must be a failure and then there could be a @AfterTest step that tries to ping the grid status with the standard JSON /status request, which if it fails, you could throw a Assert.fail .   I haven't tried this but it seems like it might work.

Also, you might be able to use [Saucerest](https://github.com/saucelabs/saucerest-java/blob/master/src/ExampleUsage.java) to query test status and possibly get a timeout reply?